# Can't use pandas in a local package

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, package

I have been working on a small wrapper for pyodbc package.  It is not much, just to simplify the syntax for the specific databases I work with a lot.

The structure is as follows

> ```
> sql
>
>    sqlFunc
>         __init__.py
>         sqlLoad.py
>    setup.py
> ```

The name of the package will be sqlFunc.

In sql load it just has a simple Class called Connect to hold the cursor and a few functions to return the data from the database in various formats.  I wanted to add returning as part of a pandas dataframe into this.  However whenever I include pandas within sqlLoad and include it in the install_requires section of the setup.py file I can't find the class when calling the package.  sqlFunc.Connect() simply gives an error but I can import sqlFunc

When I got to a new module and import sqlFunc and try and run `sqlFunc.Connect()` it says it can't find it and it does not appear if I go `print(dir(sqlFunc))`
It does however work if I use the python Console section of pycharm weirdly enough and it also works if I remove all references to pandas.

My class Connect looks like

```
class Connect:
    def __init__(self, server, username, pwd):
        connection = pyodbc.connect(...)
        self._cursor = connection.cursor()
    def execute_dataframe(self, query):
        self._cursor.execute(query)
        return pd.DataFrame(self._cursor.fetchall())
```

The ... includes some company specific info but I am simply setting the server, driver, username, password and if the connection is trusted.

My **init**.py is

> ```
> from sqlFunc import sqlLoad
> from sqlFunc.sqlLoad import Connect
> ```

My setup.py is 
from setuptools import setup

> ```
>   setup(name='sqlFunc',
>         version='0.2',
>         packages=['sqlFunc'],
>         install_requires=["pyodbc", "pandas", ],
>         zip_safe=False)
> ```

Comment: side note, `pandas.read_sql_query(connects, querytxt`) can replace your `execute_dataframe` method

Comment: how did you install your module?

Comment: installed with >python setup.py install

Thanks for the info about read_sql_query.  Pandas were an add on to this so had not realised there was a specific method.

Any more info needed?

Comment: when you executing the code, were you in the source directory?

Comment: Yes I was in the folder where the sql project is stored.  I used the same method when Pandas were not in the code